# How to show list elements one by one with fade in / fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show list elements one by one. On page load the first element is displayed, then after some time the first element fades out and the second element fade in.

What approaches are there to solve this?

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: a quick google search returns hundreds of libraries that do that for you...

Comment: you can do by css animation

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have a standard list of elements and they're initially hidden, something like this can work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#listId').children('li').each(function () {
        var appearTime = $(this).index() * 2000;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(this).fadeIn(200);
        }, appearTime);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/u0fq3m5y/2/

```
<div>div1</div>
<div>div2</div>
<div>div3</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var delay = 3000;

  $('div').each(function(i, e) {
    $(e).delay(i * delay).fadeIn().delay(delay).fadeOut();
  }); 
});
```